firefox returns odd results for file:/// or file:///tmp
Not long ago (a few months at most), Firefox on Ubuntu 22.04 was able to open files in /tmp, using a file:///tmp/xxx link.  Now these links show the files as unavailable.
When I try to use a file:/// link, the root dir is unrecognizable (and contains a README.md that I can't open from Firefox), and file:///tmp is also unrecognizable.
xdg-open file:/// shows the results I expect.
I've been using this for go tool cover, which no longer works because it creates a file in /tmp that the browser can't see.
Here are the contents of file:///, which might provide a clue.
README.md   1 KB     4/8/24     03:51:43 EDT
bin                  4/8/24     03:53:39 EDT
boot                 4/8/24     03:53:39 EDT
copyright   2 KB     4/8/24     03:51:43 EDT
dev                  7/4/24     13:52:01 EDT
etc                  7/4/24     13:52:06 EDT
home                 3/7/24     20:53:14 EST
host                 4/8/24     03:53:23 EDT
lib                  4/8/24     03:53:39 EDT
lib32                4/8/24     03:53:40 EDT
lib64                4/8/24     03:53:40 EDT
libx32               4/8/24     00:53:48 EDT
media                3/8/24     08:09:23 EST
meta                 4/8/24     03:53:40 EDT
mnt                  2/20/24    14:22:09 EST
opt                  4/8/24     00:53:49 EDT
proc                 7/4/24     09:48:40 EDT
root                 4/22/24    09:43:01 EDT
run                  7/4/24     13:24:58 EDT
sbin                 4/8/24     03:53:40 EDT
snap                 7/4/24     13:51:59 EDT
srv                  4/8/24     00:53:49 EDT
sys                  7/4/24     09:48:40 EDT
tmp                  7/4/24     14:15:56 EDT
usr                  4/8/24     03:53:27 EDT
var                  4/8/24     03:53:40 EDT
writable             4/8/24     03:53:23 EDT

I can't find a directory with these files anywhere on my system.
Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Ubuntu has switched Firefox from being a traditional package to being a Snap package – imagine it as a Docker container but for desktop apps. The container has a virtualized file system with its own / (and therefore its own /tmp and everything else), only with /home mounted from the outer namespace.
To 'fix' it, find a way to install Firefox not through Snap – e.g. using the Mozilla .deb packages from their PPA repository (use the apt-preferences file if needed to prioritize the PPAs over the bad Ubuntu package), or by extracting the Mozilla-provided .tar.gz into ~/.local or wherever (it will auto-update like on Windows).

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I consider Ubuntu to be a "normal" Linux distribution.

I just posted what might be a similar (or identical) issue here.  Is the only way to fix the problem to remove the SNAP and installing the PPA ?

Another workaround is to use TMPDIR: TMPDIR=$HOME/tmp go tool cover ...

I can't suggested edit - and it feels like too major a change to impose but the official instructions include the necessary pinning now  https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-firefox-linux#w_install-firefox-deb-package-for-debian-based-distributions
